# Is it safe to override Laravel's AuthenticatesUsers trait methods in the LoginController?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I need some custom functionality in the login and logout, for example right now I want to add restriction on the number of simultaneous connections a user can have to his account (So he can log in from up to 5 different devices).

But the LoginController is pretty empty and uses the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait.

In order to add my custom functionality, is it safe to copy the entire methods needed (In my case the `login()` and `logout()` to the `LoginController`, and then add my custom code to these methods?

Or that might have some other side effects?

Answer (score 0):

It won't be a problem. Usually, Laravel gives, you some basic authenticate functionality, but that doesn't mean you can't expand it.